# How do I add a comment to an answer that requires an image?

Tags: feature-request

[Pass Dictionary from LabVIEW to python script via a Python Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56282070/pass-dictionary-from-labview-to-python-script-via-a-python-node)

The OP starts off with TLDR, and wants to know how to serialize data to pass it from LabVIEW to Python.

Someone posts an answer that recommends using JSON. They posted multiple examples, and mention that LabVIEW JSON doesn't support conversion of a timestamp.

I have LabVIEW and Python experience, and wanted to share how to serialize a timestamp in LabVIEW to an ISO-8601 string (not a well known technique). LabVIEW is a graphical programming language and stackoverflow comments do not allow for insertion of images in comments.

I posted an answer instead to include the 'source code'. The accepted answer owner voted down my answer and commented I answered the wrong thread. I replied in the comment that I did not, and that I posted an answer because the comments do not support an image. They replied back that the OP never mentioned JSON.

I raged a bit, then decided to ask here:

***How do I add a comment to an answer that requires an image?***

Maybe a feature request to add images to comments is in order?

Comment: Is there a reason you cant provide a link that opens the image instead? maybe hosted on imgur?

Comment: *I have LabVIEW and Python experience, and wanted to share how to serialize a timestamp in LabVIEW to an ISO-8601 string (not a well known technique).* In this case, this might be a good candidate for a self-answered Q&A.

Comment: I've been a casual contributor on stackoverflow. This was my first meta question. I couldn't post without applying a tag. I selected what I thought was the most appropriate tag from the list presented. After reviewing  https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta I realized I was wrong. I assume that is why there are so many down-votes. I tried to ask a question of how to be a better contributor.  I deleted my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56282070/pass-dictionary-from-labview-to-python-script-via-a-python-node . It will be a long time before I ask or answer a question again...

Comment: Votes in meta do not affect your account in any way. While I understand it can feel harsh, no need to take it like that. Hopefully the answers you got helped you at lest.

Answer (score 7):

You can post links in comments, so you can link to whatever image is relevant to you comment. No need to embed it.

Either just the URL, which becomes clickable; or as a proper hyperlink using markdown.

E.g. doing this:

> `Posting the link to the image. Like [this](https://placekitten.com/200/300).`

Would render like this:

> Posting the link to the image. Like [this](https://placekitten.com/200/300).

What you shouldn’t do is post a comment as if it were an answer.

Because it's not an answer. It’s liable to get downvoted and/or deleted.

Comments are supposed to be lightweight. Adding support for inlining images would be completely wrong, and would open the door for extremely noisy threads.

As a feature-request, I think it's a non-starter.

Answer (score 7):

It occurs to me that the issue you might be hitting is uploading the image for use in a comment like Yivi is describing. Here's a work around to upload the image to the Stack's Imgur storage to then link to in the comment:

1. Scroll down to the answer box.
2. Upload the image as if you were going to use that image in the answer.
3. Copy the URL that appears in the answer box.
4. Use that URL in the comment for the link to the image.
5. Since the image is already uploaded independent of the answer, now you can discard the answer so that you don't accidentally post it.

If you're wanting to inline the image in the comment, I strongly disagree with a request for such a feature. Comments are supposed to be short, and the space provided for them is very small. We don't even allow line breaks in comments because of how short they're supposed to be. Introducing space to display images there would require some hefty changes to the layout of the page, and there's no real justification to do it.

Comment: If the question is closed, you can just edit the question and do this, then cancel the edit before you submit it.